# SAS - how to preserve actual numbers when importing from a csv file with numbers in scientific notation

Tags: format, sas, scientific-notation

When I imported a file with long numeric IDs from a csv file into SAS, I wanted to convert the numbers into text. But these numbers were stored in scientific notation, so when they convert, the last digits all turned into zeros.

For example, 7.3139908E14 turned ino 731399080000000, when it should be 731399076376199.

Is there anyway to work around this? Ultimately I need to do some deduping and then export this file out as a text file.

Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't look like a SAS problem, but a problem with your csv file. If you look at the csv file, do you see 7.3139908E14 or 731399076376199? If it's the first type, SAS can't have any way of knowing what the last digits are. Did you create the CSV file in Excel? If so, you need to format it differently, so it does not truncate the variables.

Comment: thanks for the answer! The problem is that I am exporting 1.5 million rows of data from a database and I have tried both saving it as a text file and csv file. With text file, I can open it but I can't change the format. With csv file, I can change the format technically speaking but it's too big that I can't open it completely.

Comment: Can you post a few rows from the .txt file and a few from the .csv?

Comment: Convert your column into a text field before saving it to the CSV.  For example, in either mySQL or SQL server databases you could do this using something like `cast(myvariable as char(30)) as my_text_var` .

Answer (score 1):

Say your data looked like (i.e. numeric ID in second CSV position):

```
blah;7313990763761997;blah
```

You could do a simple read of the file, line by line and access the input buffer directly (the _INFILE_ variable):

```
filename mycsv "\path\to\mycsv.csv";

data mydata;
  infile mycsv;
  input;
  length idvar $16;
  idvar=scan(_infile_,2,";");
run;
```

This will preserve the number in text format, if that's all you wish to do.